# Setting "Show editor for creation date time" programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to alter the common settings for a content type to show editor for creation date time. I know this can be done via admin, but I would also like to do this through code, for deployment in the future.

The problem is, I don't know what is the right name for the common part setting and the field. So far I have this:

```
.WithPart("CommonPart", builder3 => builder3
                            .WithSetting("CommonSettings.ShowCreatedUtcEditor", "true"))'
```

But it could be wrong. I see a lot online that show `commonTypePartSettings.ShowCreatedUtcEditor` but these were from way back in 2011. Not sure if that still applies.

Anybody know what it is exactly? Or some way to find it?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct setting name for date editor is now `"DateEditorSettings.ShowDateEditor"`. And corresponding setting for owner editor is `"OwnerEditorSettings.ShowOwnerEditor"`.

Comment: thanks heaps. How do you know that? I couldn't find any documentation

Comment: Code is the ultimate documentation by itself;)